# How do get a new Facebook access token invisibly when my current one expires? (Windows 8 App C#)

Tags: windows-8, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-store-apps, facebook-access-token

Within my app (following various documentations) the user is able to login in to facebook via a dedicated login page. From this, the access token is given and the I save it. The thing is to get the token this way (using `await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, loginUri, new Uri(redirectUri));`, which seems the automatically show a login screen from facebook, I honestly have no idea how it appears...) means the user *has* to type their username and password again.

I don't want this to be the case, since I think if the user has logged in once, they shouldn't need to keep typing in their details again and again. However no matter what I've tried I can seem to get a new access token without going through this login screen again.

I've tried methods using the `FacebookClient.Get()` method, however it just doesn't exist in this version of the SDK. I have no idea what to use in its place, or what I need to send to Facebook to get a response.

So far this is what I have to log in for the first time (pretty much what is on the documentation)

```
string redirectUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
            try
            {
                var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
                {
                    client_id = FacebookHandler.FacebookAppId,
                    redirect_uri = redirectUrl,
                    scope = FacebookHandler.Permissions,
                    display = "touch",
                    response_type = "token"
                });

                Uri endUri = new Uri(redirectUrl);

                WebAuthenticationResult webAuthRes = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, loginUrl, endUri);

                if (webAuthRes.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
                {
                    var callbackUri = new Uri(webAuthRes.ResponseData.ToString());
                    var facebookOAuthResult = fb.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(callbackUri);
                    var accessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                    {
                        // User is not logged in, they may have canceled the login
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // User is logged in and token was returned
                        FacebookHandler.AccessToken = accessToken;
                        LoginSucceeded();
                    }
                }

                else if (webAuthRes.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + "HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + webAuthRes.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + "Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + webAuthRes.ResponseStatus.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //
                // Bad Parameter, SSL/TLS Errors and Network Unavailable errors are to be handled here.
                //
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);

                throw ex;
            }
```

On successive launches of the app, after the user as entered their details for the first time, the saved access token could be used, but it soon expires, which throws a `FacebookOAuthException`. This is where I have tried to invisibly get a new access token, and where its not working.

```
        try
        {
            await fb.PostTaskAsync(url, argList);
        }

        catch (FacebookOAuthException exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            ValidateLoginUrl(GetLoginUrl());
            //Problem is with the ValidateLoginUrl(), which would get an access token from the login url
        }
```

One of the things I've tried was to use `TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl()`, on the loginUrl that I can get by using `FacebookClient.GetLoginUrl()` (which is successful), but when I try to parse it it just comes up with an `InvalidOperationException`, and otherwise no explanation.

What do I have to do in order to get a new access token without the user having to login in again? I have my app ID and secret, and I could probably save the users ID from the initial login for use later(?). Would any of that help do this?